# 9patch with custom background image

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch, android-shape

I've been working on this problem for 2 days now. What I'm trying to achieve is to make a bitmap fill the complete non-transparent background of a 9patch drawable (a speech bubble in this case).

Instead of this

[image]

I want something like this

[image]

(Yes, bad photoshopping, but serves its purpose.)

Is that even possible? I cannot provide any code, as I don't have any that would make my problem more clear. Sorry about that.

Regards,
D.

Comment: why not make the bubble part transparent and overlay the transparent bubble on the image

Comment: Check this thread, it's exactly what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208310/insert-imageview-in-android-chat-bubble-adjustable

Comment: @rom4ek - Unfortunately not. This guy is creating his own shape instead of using one from a 9patch :/

Comment: You can't doing it using 9patch as mentioned in that thread.